# How can I keep my theme xml file synced with the Xamarin Android designer?

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

Some background:
I was trying to implement a toolbar by replacing the ActionBar, I accidentally inherited the new theme from a noActionbar theme, so I went to try and update the parent theme, but it didn't fix the problem because Xamarin didn't synchronize that change with the designer window. I decided at this point to just start from scratch, so I went to delete the theme file, and I removed the reference from the manifest, but now I've still got the theme hanging around in the designer, image below:

[image]

Again, there is no longer a theme file, and building this as is doesn't generate a new theme file, and the manifest isn't referencing the theme either, so why does the theme hang around? Am I just flat out using themes incorrectly? I'm following exactly what every tutorial online says to do, so I'm not sure how this could be the case. Does the designer have nothing to do with the theme files you create? And if this is the case, why does Xamarin generate a theme file from the designer?

Comment: For now I just did a rollback in git to start fresh, but this is a really annoying issue and I'd still like to know how to work around it.

Comment: Seems like a bug in the Android Designer for Visual Studio to me. Did you create a bug on [Xamarin's bugzilla](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/) already? If not, I recommend that you do so. Unfortunately, it is quite difficult to assist and resolve issues like these on SO.

Comment: I assumed that would be that case, but I figured maybe someone had this issue too, I'll go and post it there.